# Adding labelling arrows to a plot

Tags: pgfplots

I want to create a graph like:
[image]
However, i have managed to create the graph but failed to:

1. Add the blue arrows to my graph,
2. Add some space between the curve and the arrows of the axes, and
3. Increasing the size of the whole tikzpicture, the graph is very small when added to a book, article document class.

Below is the output Im currently getting:
[image]
Below is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document} 
    
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfplotsset{ticks=none}
        \begin{axis}[
            scaled ticks=false,
            xmin=0,
            ymin=0,
            axis lines=middle,
            axis line style={->},
            x label style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.05)},anchor=north},
            y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.05,.5)},rotate=90,anchor=south},
            xlabel=Number of stocks in portfolio,
            ylabel=Portfoilio Risk,
            ]
            \addplot[domain=0:10, red, ultra thick,smooth] {e^(-.9*x)+.5};
            \addplot[domain=0:10, gray, dashed,thick] {1.5};
            \addplot[domain=0:10, gray,dashed,thick] {.5};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the better solution (I will prefer to use only tikz package).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document} 
    
    \begin{center}
        

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
        \pgfplotsset{ticks=none}
        \begin{axis}[
            scaled ticks=false,
            xmin=0,
            ymin=0,
            axis lines=middle,
            axis line style={->},
            x label style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.05)},anchor=north},
            y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.05,.5)},rotate=90,anchor=south},
            xlabel=Number of stocks in portfolio,
            ylabel=Portfoilio Risk,
            ]
            \addplot[domain=0:10, red, ultra thick,smooth] {e^(-.9*x)+.5};
            \addplot[domain=0:10, gray, dashed,thick] {1.5};
            \addplot[domain=0:10, gray,dashed,thick] {.5};
        \end{axis}
            \draw[latex-latex, gray, line width=5pt] (1.2,0)--(1.2,5.7) node[black,pos=.3,fill=white] () {\large\bfseries Total stock risk};
            \draw[latex-latex, gray, line width=5pt] (5,0)--(5,1.9) node[black,pos=.5,fill=white] () {\large\bfseries Undiversifiable Market Risk (Systematic Risk)};
            \draw[-latex,gray,line width=5pt] (2,5.7)--(2,2.2) node[black,pos=.5,fill=white,right] () {\large\bfseries Unsystematic Risk eliminated by diversification};; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

**ADD**: Only tikz version.
Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}    
    \begin{center}  
        \begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=10]
            \draw[thick,->] (0,0)--(12,0) node[pos=.5,below] () {\large\bfseries Number of stocks in portfolio};
            \draw[thick,->] (0,0)--(0,1.7) node[midway,left] () {\large\bfseries \rotatebox{90}{Portfoilio Risk}};
            \draw[red,line width=2pt] plot[domain=0:12,smooth] (\x,{e^(-.9*\x)+.5});
            \draw[blue,dashed] (0,1.5)--(12,1.5);
            \draw[blue,dashed] (0,.5)--(12,.5);

            \draw[latex-latex, gray, line width=5pt] (2,0)--(2,1.5) node[black,pos=.3,fill=white] () {\large\bfseries Total stock risk};
            \draw[latex-latex, gray, line width=5pt] (8,0)--(8,.5) node[black,pos=.5,fill=white] () {\large\bfseries Undiversifiable Market Risk (Systematic Risk)};
            \draw[-latex,gray,line width=5pt] (4,1.5)--(4,.53) node[black,pos=.5,fill=white,right,align=left] () {\large\bfseries Unsystematic Risk eliminated\\\large \bfseries by diversification};; 
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Problem number 2 is still outstanding. I wish to have my curve overlapped by the axes. For example, the upper part of the curve is covering the tip of the y axis arrow.

Comment: thanks for adjusting the y axis. Can the x axis be increased as well?

Comment: Yes! Replace the '12' by, for example, '14' as You wish.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know `pgfplots` well, I tried...

I created a command with 2 parameters to place text on the curve. I used `\fpeval` from `xfp` package

EDIT:

- I modify `\scale=1.5` by `\width=0.75\linewidth` to avoid that the labels are also enlarged
- I am correcting an error `\fpeval{exp{-#1*0.9}+.5}` is wrong, we have to put parentheses!

EDIT2

- with Hasan Basri Çetin's answer to this post [Draw a vertical line from x to f(x)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/680588/draw-a-vertical-line-from-x-to-fx), the `xfp` package is not useful and we can position a point on the curve with:

  `declare function ={myfun(\x) = e^(-.9*\x)+.5;},domain=0:10`

et `(axis cs: 3, {myfun(3)})`

- we can use `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` to plot the dashed segments

**the code**

```
    \documentclass{article}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/680359/adding-labelling-arrows-to-a-plot
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}%<-- added
\usetikzlibrary {arrows.meta}%<-- added
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\mycalc}[2]{%
  \draw[myarrow,->,shorten >=1pt](axis cs: #1,1.5) -- node[mytext,right]{#2} (axis cs: #1, {myfun(#1)});
}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[%scale=1.5,
    %https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/680588/draw-a-vertical-line-from-x-to-fx
    declare function ={myfun(\x) = e^(-.9*\x)+.5;},domain=0:10,
    myarrow/.style = {<->,>={Latex[length=2mm, angle=90:10pt]},blue, line width=4pt},
    mytext/.style = {black,pos=.5,fill=white,font=\bfseries\small},
    ]
    \pgfplotsset{ticks=none}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=0.75\linewidth,%<-- to replace scale=1.5
        xmin=0,
        ymin=0,
        axis lines=middle,
        axis line style={->},
        x label style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.05)},anchor=north,%font=\bfseries\large% we can 
          },
        y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.05,.5)},rotate=90,anchor=south},
        xlabel=Number of stocks in portfolio,
        ylabel=Portfoilio Risk,
      ]
      \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0.5,1.5}{
        \draw [dashed] (axis cs:0,#1) -- (axis cs:10,#1);
      }

      % \addplot[domain=0:10, red, ultra thick,smooth] {e^(-.9*x)+.5};
      \addplot[red, ultra thick,smooth] {myfun(x)};

      \draw[myarrow](axis cs: 1.5,1.5) --node[mytext,pos=0.75,xshift=5mm]{Total Stock Risk} (axis cs: 1.5,0);
      \draw[myarrow](7.5,0.5) -- node[mytext]{\parbox{4cm}{\raggedright Undiversifiable Market Risk (Systematic Risk)}} (axis cs: 7.5,0);

      \mycalc{3}{\parbox{4.8cm}{\raggedright Unsystematic Risk eliminated by diversification}}

    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The second arrow is not like OP question.

Comment: @Raffaelle Santoro Thank you, I don't know how I managed to see a 3rd line.