# Draw a vertical line from x to f(x)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have created a TikZ plot with PGFPlots. I have labeled `x1` and want to draw a line between `x1` and `f(x1)`. How can I do just that?

```tex
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:2]
    \begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=2,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=2,
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$f(x)$,
    ytick={0},
    xtick={1},
    xticklabels={$x_{1}$}
    ]
    \addplot[color=red]{x^3-2*x^2+1/2*x+1};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here's my plot:

[image: the plot]

Answer (score 13):

Declare your function in tikz and find point on curve.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
          declare function ={ myfun(\x) = \x^3-2*\x^2+1/2*\x+1;}, 
                           domain=0:2
                    ]
    \begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=2,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=2,
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$f(x)$,
    ytick={0},
    xtick={1},
    xticklabels={$x_{1}$},
          ]
            \addplot[ color=red] {myfun(x)};
            \coordinate (M) at (1, {myfun(1)});
            \filldraw (M) circle[radius=0.5pt];
            \draw (M)--(1,0);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]